# How to Run AJAX After Component is Loaded in Polymer

Tags: ajax, lifecycle, polymer-2.x

I am trying to automatically run this AJAX call in a parent component, but am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined` error.  I have looked through the Polymer lifecycle methods and none of them seem to ensure the AJAX element being loaded before calling it.

```
<template>
  <iron-ajax id="ajax"
    url="https://api/endpoint"
    method="post"
    handle-as="json"
    content-type="application/json"
    body="[[request]]"
    last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
 </template>
```

**Define properties: apiKey, username, etc.**

```
connectedCallback() {
  this.setCredentials();
}

setCredentials() {
  this.set('username', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
  this.set('apiKey', sessionStorage.getItem('apiKey'));
  this.getResponse();
}

getResponse() {
  if (this.username && this.apiKey && this.$.ajax != undefined) {
    this.request = {
      "username": this.username,
      "apiKey": this.apiKey,
      "text": "some text"
    };
    let request = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    request.completes.then(req => {
      // do something
    })
  } else {
    this.getResponse();
  }
}
```

How can I ensure the entire document is ready to make the AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

This below way may more effective to ensure the entire document is ready :

```
static get observers() {
  return [  'checkUsernameAndApiKey(username, apiKey)' ];
}

ready() {
  super.ready();
     setTimeout(()=>{
           // In order to wait this property loaded async with another ways
           this.set('username', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
           this.set('apiKey', sessionStorage.getItem('apiKey'));
     }, 900)

}

checkUsernameAndApiKey(u, a) {
  // if failed to get sessionStorage, u or a will be undefined.
  if (u && a) {
    this.set('request', {"username": this.username, "apiKey": this.apiKey, "text": "some text"};
    this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    ...
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/oEwXxy)

Answer (score 0):

When I want an XHR request to load with my element, I use the `ready()` method:

```
<template>
  <iron-ajax id="ajax"
    url="https://api/endpoint"
    method="post"
    handle-as="json"
    content-type="application/json"
    body="[[request]]"
    on-response="_checkUsernameAndApiKey"
    on-error="_handleError">
  </iron-ajax>
</template>

...

ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
}

_checkUsernameAndApiKey(e) {
  if (e.detail.response) {
    let response = e.detail.response;
    ...
  } else {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }
}

_handleError(e) {
  console.log(e.detail.error);
}
```